# Is the axiom of choice necessary to define this function from 1-dimensional $T$-invariant subspaces to eigenvalues of T?

Tags: linear-algebra, axiom-of-choice

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$, and let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation.  Define the following two sets
$$
A = \{W \colon W \subseteq V \text{ is a 1-dimensional subspace of $V$ satisfying $T(W) \subseteq W$} \}
$$
and
$$
B = \{\lambda \in F \colon \text{ $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$} \}.
$$
I would like to define a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ as follows.  Given $W \in A$, choose any non-zero vector $w \in W$, and define $f(W) = \lambda$, where $\lambda \in F$ is such that $T(w) = \lambda w$.  I have two questions.

1. Does my definition of $f$ require the Axiom of Choice?
2. If my description requires it, can the same function be described in a way that does not require the Axiom of Choice?

(Admission 1: I have no hesitation assuming the Axiom of Choice, I just don't feel like it should be required here.  Admission 2: I haven't thought much about the Axiom of Choice, so this could be a very misguided question.)

Overall my intuition is that since every choice of non-zero $w \in W$ results in the same output $\lambda$, that should help us, but I get more confused the more I think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this does not ultimately require choice. Consider the following slight modification of your definition:

> We set $f(W)=\lambda$ iff for every nonzero $w\in W$ we have $T(w)=\lambda w$.

*(The "nonzero" there is of course unnecessary, but it's useful to include it to demonstrate the general pattern.)*

This doesn't invoke choice at all. The point is that when the outcome of a process is independent of a choice made along the way, we can "de-choicify" by asking about the universal behavior.

*(Note that we could also go with "for some" - but then the nonzero-ness requirement would not be redundant. In general I prefer the "for every" approach. That said, sometimes - e.g. in computability theory - we want both simultaneously.)*

Comment: Great thank you!  I'm not sure how well-defined this question is, but would you say my definition above does require Axiom of Choice as written?

Comment: @CJD: Choice is needed to argue that this situation is not somehow trivial, namely that there is some $T$ which is not given by $Tv=\lambda v$ for all $v\in V$. But choice is not needed for this. This is the same for defining infinite products of sets: the definition works without choice just fine, it's just that we cannot prove that the product is non-empty without assuming choice.

Comment: @CJD I would say that the translation is automatic enough that it ultimately does not. But this is  a bit subjective.